# Jhipster Docker-compose conflict

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster

I am attempting to use [jhipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) to generate a [microservices architecture](http://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) set of apps. From within the [jhipster-devbox](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox), I do the following:

`$ mkdir mygateway && cd mygateway`

`$ yo jhipster` - select gateway, answer all questions

`$ ./gradlew bootRepackage -Pdev buildDocker` want to make sure this all runs locally before I try to move it to AWS

`$ cd.. && mkdir myapi && && cd myapi`

`$ yo jhipster` - select microservices app (same package name as gateway...don't know if that matters, but not for this question)

`$ ./gradlew bootRepackage -Pdev buildDocker`

`$ cd .. && mkdir docker-compose && cd docker-compose`

`$ yo jhipster:docker-compose` (all items have run successfully to this point)

`$ docker-compose up -d` returns:

> ERROR: Conflict. The name "/jhipster-registry" is already in use by
>   container
>   a785f619b5dd985b3ff30a8ed6e41066795eb8b5e108d2549cd4a9d5dc27710a. You
>   have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.

It would appear the "jhipster-registry" is available inside the `gateway` and `api` apps I just created... I tried commenting them out of the `app.yml` file to no success?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem but it's that you already have a docker container named "jhipster-registry". I imagine it's because you already had created at least 1 other jhipster microservices stack with docker before. If you remove the jhipster-registry container (i.e. `docker rm jhipster-registry`) and then `run docker-compose up -d` again, you should be fine as it will recreate the container. I'm not sure why the jhipster-registry container doesn't get prefixed by the directory it's in (as the other containers in the stack do). I think it has to do with the jhipster-registry.yml file that specifically names the container "jhipster-registry".

Comment: Thanks @sdoxsee I'll give that a shot. That's what I thought and I was reading the `docker-composer` docs and kept running `docker-composer ps` and didnt see anything

Comment: try `docker ps -a`